# drupal twitter service link

Tags: drupal, twitter, module

i'm using **service link module** and tries to add twitter link as below

```
if (variable_get('service_links_show_twitter', 0)) {
$turl = drupal_http_request('http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url='. $url);
$turl = isset($turl->data) ? $turl->data : urldecode($url) ;

$links['service_links_twitter'] = theme('service_links_build_link', t('Twitter'), "http://www.twitter.com/home/?status=$turl". "+".$title, t('Share on Twitter.'), 'images/twitter.png', $nodelink);
```

}

but the resulted tweet as below .

```
 http%3A%2F%2Ftestsite%2Fbabycare%2Ffeeding%2Fmy-art-title.
```

whats wrong with the above code and how generating valid output like

> my article title - mysite_url:
>   http://bit.ly/68Vg1O

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it gets a properl url from TinyURL?
Can you add a `print $turl;` before `$links['service_links_twitter']..`? and see what it gives you?